# Как сразу получить значение по свечам 200 монет Binance?

Tags: python

Друзья. Используя Binance API я получаю данные свечей за последние 30 минут.
Мне необходимо за несколько секунд добавить значения свечей по 200 токенам.
Чтобы отправить запрос API на получение свечей, нужен сгенерированный timestamp, соответственно, если я правильно понимаю, я могу отправить только один запрос в секунду.

Но мне нужно сделать это быстрее, чтобы весь процесс занял 2-5 секунд. Подскажите, что можно придумать ? Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 0):

Доречі, нещодавно дізнався про медіа на тему криптограмотності «Crypto вісник», ніби цікава інформація, особливо для людей, які поки не дуже розуміються у крипті. Але сторінку ведуть українською, тому може не всім підійти, проте рекомендую почитати.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).